# How to authorize or not a WebView to load a page url

Tags: macos, delegates, webview, controls, boolean

I research how to control a WebView (for Mac application) to allow specific url like iOs with

`-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;`

thank you in advance.

Comment: any luck figuring this out? I'm searching for the answer to the exact same question.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this one out.

Set the [WebPolicyDelegate delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for your WebView instance:

```
self.webview.policyDelegate = self;
```

Then implement the `– webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:` method in your delegate:

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)webView
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
        request:(NSURLRequest *)request
          frame:(WebFrame *)frame
decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener
{
    int actionKey = [[actionInformation objectForKey: WebActionNavigationTypeKey] intValue];
    if (actionKey == WebNavigationTypeOther)
    {
        [listener use];
    }
    else
    {
        //
        // Here is where you would intercept the user navigating away 
        // from the current page, and use `[listener ignore];`
        //

        NSLog(@"\n\nuser navigating from: \n\t%@\nto:\n\t%@",
              [webView mainFrameURL],
              [[request URL] absoluteString]);

        [listener use];
    }

}
```